# Tangent plane to a surface at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have a function $f(x,y) = x \sin(xy) + 2$. The equation for the tangent plane to the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ at the point $(a,b)$ is given by $$z = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)$$

So let's say our point is $(\pi, 1)$. I can mostly simply use the equation above but for $f_x$ the partial derivative is messy. Wolfram alpha says it is $x(x y'(x) +y)\cos(xy)+\sin(xy)$. How should you deal with the $y'(x)$ term? For the other $x$ and $y$ you simply plug in the coordinates of the point, but with the $y'(x)$ term I'm stumped. Perhaps there is a different form of the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$. Here, it isn't; it's independent of $x$. That means you can substitute $y'(x)=0$.

Another neat trick: If you want to find $f_x(a,b)$, you can take the derivative of $f(x,b)$ with respect to $x$, then substitute $x=a$. A similar trick works for $f_y(a,b)$.